# Relationship between proper orthochronous Lorentz group $SO^+(1,3)$ and $SU(2)\times SU(2)$, or their Lie algebras

Tags: group-theory, physics, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have seen sources claim that $SO^+(1,3) \cong SU(2) \times SU(2)$, but have seen others claim that only their Lie algebras are isomorphic.

1. Is it true that $SO^+(1,3) \cong SU(2) \times SU(2)$?
2. If not, is $SO^+(1,3)$ isomorphic to some quotient of $SU(2) \times SU(2)$?
3. Is the analogous result true for their Lie alebras, i.e. $\mathfrak{so}^+(1,3) \cong \mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)$, or something similar?
4. Generally, when can you go from a product group isomorphism to a corresponding result for Lie algebras, or vice versa?

I'm led to believe there is some isomorphism of this form since (I think) $$SO^+(1,3) \cong PSL(2,\mathbb{C}), \quad SL(2,\mathbb{C}) \cong SO(4), \quad SO(4) \cong SU(2) \times SU(2)/\{\pm I\}.$$

Comment: I may be completely off, but isn't the Lorentz group non-compact while $SU(2) \times SU(2)$ is compact.

Comment: Please, state what your "sources" are.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639749/precise-connection-between-complexification-of-mathfraksu2-mathfrakso?rq=1

Comment: Related Phys.SE post https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108212/2451

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$SO^+(3,1)$ is the so-called *restricted Lorentz group*, which is the identity component of the Lorentz group $SO(3,1)$. It is a six-dimensional real Lie group, which is not simply connected.

1. Since $SO^+(1,3)$ is not compact, but $SU(2)\times SU(2)$ is compact, the groups cannot be isomorphic as real Lie groups.
2. We have $SO^+(3,1)\simeq SL(2,\mathbb{C})/\mathbb{Z}_2\simeq SU(2)_{\mathbb{C}}/\mathbb{Z}_2$, i.e., the **complexification** of the restricted Loretz group satisfies $$SO^+(3,1)_{\mathbb{C}}\simeq (SU(2)_{\mathbb{C}}\times SU(2)_{\mathbb{C}})/\mathbb{Z}_2.$$
3. In the same way, $\mathfrak{so}^+(3,1)_{\mathbb{C}}\simeq \mathfrak{su}(2)_{\mathbb{C}}\oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)_{\mathbb{C}}\simeq \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})\oplus \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: How would these answers change if I replaced $SO^+(1,3)$ with $SO(1,3)$?

Comment: For the Lie algebra it would not matter, because we have $\mathfrak{so}^+(3,1)=\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$.

Comment: Is $SO(3,1)_\mathbb{C} \cong SU(2)_\mathbb{C} \times SU(2)_\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes, it is. The complexification of $SO(3,1)$ is $SL(2,\mathbb{C})\times SL(2,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  May I ask is SU(2)xSU(2) the tensor product? (i.e. SU(2)⊗SU(2))

Comment: No, it is the direct product.