# What does it mean that some group is "a form of some Lie algebra"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

For example, the Lie algebras of $SO(4)$ and $SO(3,1)$ are the same, called $D_2$ and isomorphic to $A_1 \times A_1$ ($= \mathfrak{su}(2)\times \mathfrak{su}(2)$).

Thus $SO(4)$ is a ([...] compact?) form of $D_2$ and $SO(3,1)$ is a ([...] non-compact?) form of $D_2$

In addition, for almost every Lie group the Wikipedia article talks about the various forms of the Lie algebra (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E6_(mathematics))).

What does it really mean that there are several (non-isomorphic) groups which are "forms of the same Lie algebra"?

Comment: See [compact real form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_form_(Lie_theory)#Construction_of_the_compact_real_form) of a complex semisimple Lie algebra.

Comment: Correctly speaking, a real form of a complex Lie algebra should be a real Lie algebra with the former as complexification). Referring to the groups as "forms" is just informal language.

Comment: @YCor Thanks,, this helps me!

Comment: It is not true that the Lie algebras of $SO(4)$ (called $\mathfrak{so}_4$) and $SO(3,1)$ (called $\mathfrak{so}_{3,1}$) are the same. The first one is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{su}_2 \oplus \mathfrak{su}_2$, the second is not. Their *complexifications* are isomorphic, namely both isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C) \oplus \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$. Which exactly means that those two (real) Lie algebras are real forms of this complex Lie algebra. Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3258221/96384 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/639749/96384.