# What happens if a Lie algebra is a direct sum of two Lie subalgebras?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

Suppose that we have a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of a Lie group G, what can I say about the latter if I can find two Lie subalgefbras $\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}\subset\mathfrak{g}$?

I'm asking this question because in my notes that's written that the Lie algebra of the proper orthocronus Lorentz group $\mathcal{L}_{+}^{\uparrow}$ can be decomposed into
$$\mathfrak{so}(1,3)=\mathfrak{su}(2)\oplus\mathfrak{su}(2)$$
so that we conclude
$$SO(1,3) ≃ SU(2)\otimes SU(2)$$
How do we reach that conclusion?

Comment: What you found in your notes is simply wrong.

Comment: Well, tbh the implication was the opposite with respect to the one I've written above. Is it also wrong? I mean the generators don't commute so I guess is still wrong

Comment: Both isomorphisms are wrong.

Comment: Do you know if there is something that we can say more generally? Forgetting about this relation

Comment: If you just can find two subalgebras, not much can be said, one needs more info. For instance that the subalgebras commute with each other.

Comment: Note the $\mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2) \cong \mathfrak{so}(3,1)$ (incorrect) isomorphism is commonly referred to by physicists but what they really mean is that they both complexify to the same complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathfrak{so}(4,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2229248/relationship-of-mathfrakso1-3-to-mathfraksu2-oplus-mathfraksu2) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639749/precise-connection-between-complexification-of-mathfraksu2-mathfrakso) for more confused physicists on exactly this issue.

Comment: Thank you, I still don't understand how can be showed the isomorphism $\mathfrak{su(2)_{\mathbb{C}}} ≃ \mathfrak{sl(2,\mathbb{C})}$, do you know some good reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Moishe says in the comments, both of the stated isomorphisms are incorrect. I will assume that the real question is in the title rather than the body: what can we say if a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is the direct sum (of Lie algebras) of two subalgebras $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{b}$?

What we can conclude is that if $G, A, B$ are the [unique simply-connected Lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group%E2%80%93Lie_algebra_correspondence#The_correspondence) with Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{b}$ then

$$G \cong A \times B.$$

A *correct* example of this is that $\mathfrak{so}(4)$ decomposes into a direct sum $\mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)$, which gives an exceptional isomorphism

$$Spin(4) \cong SU(2) \times SU(2).$$

However $\mathfrak{so}(1, 3)$ is simple, so it is not the direct sum of two of its subalgebras. It does have an exceptional isomorphism to $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$, meaning it can be written as a direct sum of *vector spaces* $\mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus i \mathfrak{su}(2)$, since $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ is the complexification of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. However, $i \mathfrak{su}(2)$ is *not* a subalgebra, so this is not a direct sum of Lie algebras.