# Lorentz algebra problem. Relation of $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1)$, $\mathfrak{s}{u}(2)$, $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: lie-algebras, physics, clifford-algebras

In the chapter 7 problems of Hall's *Lie Groups, Lie Algerbas and Representations* we have the following one:

14. Show that the real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{R}}$ (If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a complex simple Lie algebra let $\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{R}$ denote the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ viewed as a real Lie algebra of twice the dimension). Conclude that $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1)$ is simple as a real Lie algebra, but that $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1)_\mathbb{C}$ is not simple and is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})\oplus\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})$.

Also says:
Hint: First show that  $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1)_{\mathbb{C}}\cong\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})\oplus\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})$ and then show that the two copies of $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})$ are conjugates of each other.

So, I'm a physics student and I know how to do this problem using the conmutation relations of $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1)$ but now that I'm trying to understand Lie theory formally I dont even know where to start this problem. The hint even confuses me in that I dont know how to show they are conjugates of each other.

Also, in physics we use $\mathfrak{s}{u}(2)$ not $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})$ I know that $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})\cong \mathfrak{s}{u}(2)_{\mathbb{C}}$ but still confuses me. In general I'm very confunsed about all of this.

Also, I want to ask what's the relation of all of this with the Dirac Clifford algebra doesn't have to do with the problem but I know there is, obviously because we use it, but I don't see it at this formal level.

Any light will be welcomed!

Comment: "I know that $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{C}}\cong \mathfrak{s}{u}(2)$"- is plain wrong.

Comment: @MoisheKohan omg sorry I write it down in reverse. I'm editing it sorry and thanks!

Comment: Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/639749/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3258221/96384 (especially further links in "Related Questions") , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1109369/96384, and recently https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4776715/96384 for that "complexification creates two copies" business.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I have read some of that posts but now I really think i'm even more confused. Are the following isomorphisms true? $(\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1)_{\mathbb{C}})_{\mathbb{R}} \cong (\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{C}})_{\mathbb{R}} \cong  \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{R}}\oplus \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{R}}$ and if so how do i get from there the result $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{R}} \cong \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1)$ ?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I thought of $(\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1) \oplus \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1) )_{\mathbb{R}} \cong \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1)_{\mathbb{R}} \oplus \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1)_{\mathbb{R}} \cong \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1) \oplus \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1)\cong \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{R}}\oplus \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{R}}$ and then $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1) \cong \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{R}}$ but although I get the result I don't think is done properly.

Comment: ah and of course im my first comentary of these 3 im saying that $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{C}}=\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})$ assuming that the two $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})$ copies are conjugates of each other but, although I know how this is done using conmutation, realations, I dont how a more abstract, If that's the point, way of doing so.

Comment: Well in your first comment, you just use what you want to prove, for the last isomorphism. -- I do not understand what you say or ask in your latest comment.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg what isomorphism? how can I do it then?

Comment: I mean, it seems you want to conclude from $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1)\oplus\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1)\cong\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{R}}\oplus\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{R}}$ that $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{o}(3,1)\cong\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{C})_{\mathbb{R}}$, but how do you show the first isomorphism without already using the second?

Comment: As for "how to prove it then". Well either you follow the methods in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4759891/96384, or you follow the hint there. For that, the first thing to do is show the complexification of $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$ is a direct sum of two copies of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$. For that, you might want to look at explicit bases and relations, e.g. the $K_j$ and $J_j$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3258221/96384.

Comment: Then, you are supposed to show that complex conjugation flips those two copies. Again, this is probably best seen by continuing using certain basis elements. --- Once one has that, now it is time for a hammer from a big theory. When you are given a complex Lie algebra which you know is given as complexification $\mathbb C \otimes \mathfrak g$ of a real form $\mathfrak g$, and you have how complex conjugation operates on the complex version, then you get the real form by looking at the *fixed space of conjugation*. Now if conjugation flips those two copies, the fixed space can be identified ...